# After uploading an image to ftp server it cannot be opened - the format has changed

Tags: spring-boot, ftp, upload, thymeleaf, file-format

I have a problem with my spring boot application.
When I upload a file to my ftp server, the file somehow changes its format.
I cannot open the pictures anymore.

I upload them via thymeleaf.
In Controller I use upload service`with the method below:

```
    public void fileUpload(MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            FtpClient ftp = new FtpClient(ftpHost, ftpPort, ftpUser, ftpPassword);
            ftp.open();
            String tmpdir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
            File physicalFile = new File(tmpdir+file.getOriginalFilename());
            file.transferTo(physicalFile);
            ftp.putFileToPath(physicalFile, file.getOriginalFilename());
            ftp.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

And here are my FtpClient methods:

```
public void open() throws IOException {
    ftp = new FTPClient();

    ftp.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));

    ftp.connect(server, port);
    int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
    if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
        ftp.disconnect();
        throw new IOException("Exception in connecting to FTP Server");
    }

    ftp.login(user, password);
}

public void close() throws IOException {
    ftp.disconnect();
}

public void putFileToPath(File file, String path) throws IOException {
    ftp.storeFile(path, new FileInputStream(file));
}
```

Everything works- the file appears on the server, it has even the same weight.
... but I cannot open it.
Any graphic program I try to use to open it says that it is a wrong file format...

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: since when does a file have "weight" ?

Comment: since Newton found out gravity

Comment: are you sure the two files (local and remote) have the same size (in bytes!)., if not, see this about `setFileTypd`   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44194256/download-a-single-file-via-ftp-with-spring-integration

Comment: actually I have checked it and the difference is like 1 byte

Comment: With the `filetype` you can change from ASCII to BINARY transfer. You need this file transferred BINARY to keep the same size.  (i do not know if that changes weight too )

Comment: Well, weight of conputer for sure not :)

Comment: Well, I have added {ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);}    but nothing have changed. Some jpg files cannot be read, some are destroyed in half, pdf files are destroyed too (missing text, lines, etc,)

Comment: over ftp.login(user, password); line

Comment: YEAH !!!  thanx, it works now!!! over was before, and it should be after :) thanx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my FtpClient class - I have added one line
in void open() method:

```
public void open() throws IOException {
    ftp = new FTPClient();

    ftp.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
    ftp.connect(server, port);
    int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
    if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
        ftp.disconnect();
        throw new IOException("Exception in connecting to FTP Server");
    }

    ftp.login(user, password);

    //      IT WAS THE PROBLEM - I didn't have it:
    ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

}
```

thanks for help