# can I call ftp api from spring boot application to download pdf file

Tags: spring-boot, ftp, resttemplate

Recently as I was working on some mobile bill related project,
I have been given one ftp url (below). This url takes mobile number as parameter. I have been told that in response it gives back pdf file.

I have never worked on calling ftp api from spring boot application. Anyways below is the ftp url:

```
ftp://phoneApp:phoneApp@10.60.1.140/{MobileNumber}.pdf
```

In above url, I have to take MobileNumber as input parameter from user and pass the same internally in this ftp url.

Can I call it using RestTemplate. If yes.. how? Is it really possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Integration's [FtpRemoteFileTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/ftp/session/FtpRemoteFileTemplate.html) to download files via the FTP protocol.

Please also check the following post that contains some sample code: [Download a single file via FTP with Spring Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44194256/download-a-single-file-via-ftp-with-spring-integration).